# AJAX call doesn't work after submitting a form

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

This is my code at www.domain-a.de/external.search.js. I call it from  www.domain-b.de/test.php:

```js
(function ($) {
      // make the ajax request
      $.getJSON('http://www.domain-a.de/external-search.js?jsoncallback=?', function(data) {
        // append the form to the container
        $('#embedded_search').append(data);
        $('#embedded_search form').attr('action','');

        myUrl = 'http://www.domain-a.de/get-form-values?jsoncallback=?'
        var frm = $('#embedded_search form');
        
        // click on submit button
        frm.submit(function (ev) {  
          $.getJSON( myUrl )
            .done(function( json ) {
              console.log( "JSON Data: " + json );
            })
            .fail(function( jqxhr, textStatus, error ) {
              var err = textStatus + ", " + error;
              console.log( "Request Failed: " + err );
            });
        });    
      });      
})(jQuery);
```

After running this code I don't get any message in console. What is wrong with that code?

Comment: Submitting a form causes a page load, so nothing after the submit will take place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
frm.submit(function (ev) {
  ev.preventDefault();
.....rest of code.
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is not calling the `submit` handler on the item, it is simply binding it. You should do the `frm.submit(function` binding outside of your `$.getJSON` callback; then inside the callback add

```
frm.submit()
```

Which triggers the event.

Also, when the submit happens, your actions will take place but then the form will submit to the back end as normal, causing a page reload.

After the line

```
frm.submit(function (ev) {
```

Add

```
ev.preventDefault();
```

So your overall code should be

```
(function ($) {
  var frm = $('#embedded_search form');
  var myUrl = 'http://www.domain-a.de/get-form-values?jsoncallback=?'

  frm.submit(function (ev) {
      ev.preventDefault();

      $.getJSON( myUrl )
        .done(function( json ) {
          console.log( "JSON Data: " + json );
        })
        .fail(function( jqxhr, textStatus, error ) {
          var err = textStatus + ", " + error;
          console.log( "Request Failed: " + err );
        });
    }); 

  // make the ajax request
  $.getJSON('http://www.domain-a.de/external-search.js?jsoncallback=?', function(data) {
    // append the form to the container
    $('#embedded_search').append(data);
    $('#embedded_search form').attr('action','');


    // click on submit button
     frm.submit();  
  });      
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: Note that it will prevent form submit. @Headache